# CSS IDs not working when extension is hidden

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

I developed my site with extensions visible, but when I finished and wanted to make it to production. Now I did a htaccess to hide extensions and add a trailing slash, when people click on a button which redirects/links to #tab1, the url becomes:
http://domain.com/terms/#tab1

And the CSS ID doesn't open up (the tab).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is very vague and hard to understand. Please explain what you mean by "with extensions visible" and by "I finished". post your `.htaccess` code so that we can see what you did. Also post the code that you expect to open "tab1", whatever that is. We simply cannot help if you do not post your code.

Comment: perhaps it is because of the trailing '/' . Try doing `terms#tab1`